# regex matching content between patterns with condition in environment of the same patterns Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Need to match pattern: `[[ : ]]`,

I do: `\[\[(?!\[\[).[:]+.*?\]\]`

But when pattern have environment with many same patterns
like this: `[[:]] [[  []  ]] [[]] [[ :  ]] [[ : ]]`
matching is fail, and return: [[ :  ]], [[ : ]]

Or if regex is: `\[\[.*?[:]+.*?\]\]` , giving the:

```
[[  []  ]] [[]] [[ :  ]] instead of [[ :  ]]
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/7401)

What is the true way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pattern that you need to match? If you simply need to match the pattern `[[ : ]]` then you could just use `\[\[ : \]\]`

Comment: Maybe `\[\[[^][:]*:[^][]*]]`? Or can your `[[ : ]]` contain single `[` and `]` inside? Then you need `\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|]])[^:])*:.*?]]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/qvvctf/1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to match `[[ : ]]`-like strings you should match `[[` first, then any 0+ chars that are not `:` and do not start a leading/closing sequence, that is, `[[` and `]]`, then you need to match a `:` char, and then any 0+ chars up to the first (leftmost) occurrence of `]]`.

The pattern you may use is

```
\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|]])[^:])*:.*?]]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qvvctf/1). Remember to use `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` for the `.` to match across multiple lines.

**Details**

- `\[\[` - a `[[` substring
- `(?:(?!\[\[|]])[^:])*` - a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any char other than a `:` (see `[^:]` negated character class), 0+ times (see `*`), that does not start a `[[` and `]]` sequences
- `:` - a colon
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `]]` - a `]]` substring.